# MacBook won't turn on after speaker replacement

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, battery, charging

I was dumb enough to not disconnect the battery first, so I disconnected the headphone jack, then disconnected the battery and everything else. After the replacement, my Mac won't turn on, SMC reset doesn't work and the charger LED doesn't light up (!).

What does that mean, if the charger doesn't recognise the MacBook? Normally it should even when the logic board is toast, right?

It's an early 2013 A1425 MBP

Comment: What year/model macbook is it? And please add detailed steps about what you did leading up to this issue.

Comment: Check that you did reconnect everything correctly. There could always be a chance that you broke something.